# R Shiny: Modify output values in a data frame

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

The following simple shiny app displays a word and its sentiment as stored in the R data frame named `sent`.

```
library(shiny)

sent <- data.frame(word=c('happy', 'sad', 'joy', 'upset'),
                   sentiment=c('positive', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = 'num', label='', value=1, min=1, max=nrow(sent)),
  br(),
  h4("Word:"),
  textOutput('word'),
  br(),
  h4("Sentiment:"),
  textOutput('sentiment')
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$word <- renderText({ sent$word[input$num] })
  output$sentiment <- renderText({ sent$sentiment[input$num] })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

I would like to modify this in 2 ways:

(1) I would like the user to be able to scroll through the words in the column `sent$word`, rather than using `numericInput()`

(2) More importantly, I would like the user to be able to modify the sentiment value associated with each word. Ideally, this would be a drop down menu (with 'positive' and 'negative' as options), which would display the current sentiment value stored in `sent` for that word, but which could be changed by the user and overridden in the dataframe.

Any suggestions?

Comment: look into / google on `reactive` variables in shiny..

Comment: You can use `selectizeInput()` instead of `numericInput()` for a drop-down selection of words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
 library(shiny)

 sent <- data.frame(word=c('happy', 'sad', 'joy', 'upset'),
                   sentiment=c('positive', 'negative', 'positive', 'negative'),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 sent2 <- reactiveVal(sent)

 i <- 1
 i2 <- reactiveVal(i)

 ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("wordSelect"),
  br(),
  h4("Word:"),
  textOutput('word'),
  br(),
  h4("Sentiment:"),
  textOutput('sentiment'),
  br(),
  uiOutput("change"),
  actionButton("go","Change")
)

 server <- function(input, output){

  output$wordSelect <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(inputId = 'wrd', label='select word', choices=sent$word, selected=sent$word[i2()])
  })

  output$word <- renderText({ input$wrd })
  output$sentiment <- renderText({  sent$sentiment[which(sent2()$word==input$wrd)] })

 observeEvent(input$go, {
    out <- sent
    out$sentiment[which(sent$word==input$wrd)] <- input$newLabel
    sent <<- out
    sent2(out)
    i <<- which(sent$word==input$wrd)+1
    if(i > length(sent$word)) {
      i <<- i - 1
    }
    i2(i)
})

  output$change <- renderUI({
    radioButtons("newLabel", label="Change value", choices=c('positive','negative'), sent$sentiment[which(sent2()$word==input$wrd)])
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The adjusted output is first stored in a reactiveVal named `sent2()`. This is required for you see the adjure values while running the Shiny App.

A `selectizeInput()` is used to scroll through the words (Q1).

`radioButtons()` are used to select `positive` and `negative` values. The default value is whatever value is currently applied to the corresponding word.

An `actionButton()` is used to make the change when wanted.

UPDATE: I added `sent <<- out` so that your `sent` dataframe actually gets updated. Be aware that this will overwrite the values you had stored in `sent` before.

UPDATE: Each time the action button is clicked, the index of the currently selected word is determined using `which()`. Then it is incremented and stored in `i` and `i2()`. The new index is used to determine the default value of `selectizeInput()`. This way, when no manual selection of words is done, you will scroll through all options. When a word is selected manually, you will continue incrementing from that word onwards. When the last word is reached, the value does not increment further

Comment: Thanks @MKBakker - this works well! One further request: Is it possible to automatically move to the next word (row in `sent`) when the Change `actionButton` is clicked?

Comment: @Miguel Updated this now

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.